# Pushing bytes32 to array

Tags: solidity, web3js, testrpc

I am trying to push a bytes32 to an array, but it stays empty.

This is (part of) my code:

```
contract Voting {
    bytes32[] public encryptedVotes;
    bytes32[] public candidateList;
    address[] public pollingStationList;
    address public owner;
    function Voting(bytes32[] _candidateList, address[] _pollingStationList) public {
        candidateList = _candidateList;
        pollingStationList = _pollingStationList;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function vote(bytes32 encryptedVote) public {
        encryptedVotes.push(encryptedVote);
    }

    function getEncryptedVotes() view public returns (bytes32[]) {
        return encryptedVotes;
    }
}
```

Don't mind the "encrypted" part of the code, it's part of more logic.

The problem lies in the "vote" function. When I call it it with web3, "contractInstance.vote.call("a value")", it returns [] but doesn't change the state. Calling getEncryptedVotes returns [].

Is there some logic surrounding bytes32 I am failing to see? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with how you're calling it. Using ".call" of a contract function wont create a transaction, it'll do a read only call of the function. This is used for constant/view functions. So when you call `contractInstance.vote.call("a value")`, it'll run the function *off-chain* and not update the state. You should be able to just call `constractInstance.vote("a value")`, which will actually update the state of the contract.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's always these little things... Do you think I should delete this question because the question has little correlation to the answer?

Comment: No problem. I've definitely had this issue a couple of times. Don't worry about deleting it, people will likely run into the same issue not realizing the actual cause.